A Nowhere Locally Bounded and Non-Riemann Integrable Function
Here is the Example 1.16 of Sheldon Axler's Measure, Integration & Real Analysis.
Let $r_1,r_2,\dots$ be a sequence that includes each rational number in $(0,1)$ exactly once and that includes no other numbers. For $k\in \mathbf{Z}^*$, define $f_k\colon [0,1]\to \mathbf{R}$ by
$$
  f_k(x) = \begin{cases}
  \frac{1}{\sqrt{x-r_k}},&\quad\text{if $x>r_k$},\\
  0,&\quad\text{if $x\leq r_k$},
\end{cases}
$$
and define
$$
  f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{f_k(x)}{2^k}.
$$
As any subinterval contains a rational number, this function is unbounded on any subinterval of $[0,1]$.
My question is: why $f$ can be defined on any point $x\in [0,1]$? In other words, why the series
$$
  \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{f_k(x_0)}{2^k}
$$
converges for any $x_0\in [0,1]$?
Obstacles
By my limited knowledge (on Calculus), the sequence $\{r_k\}$ cannot be either monotone or convergent, by the dense property of $\mathbf{Q}$ in $\mathbf{R}$. Therefore, the Ratio Test or the Root Test of geometric series failed here. I also tried the rearrangement method, and still, due to the dense property, it did not work.
What I have only found is that: as the term $f_k(x)/2^k$ make sense if $x>r_k$, it suffices to show $f(1)$ can be defined.
What am I expecting
It would be best if you solved this problem by only knowledge in Calculus. If advanced knowledge is required, please leave the link or address where I can learn about it.

I don't think that "it suffices to show $f(1)$ can be defined".

@AnneBauval Well you are right. "$f(1)$ can be defined" is only equivalent to $f(r)$ can be defined for any rational $r$.

I don't think so either.

You are not quoting Axler faithfully. He writes:$$f:[0,1]\to[0,\infty\color{red}].$$This answers your question.

@AnneBauval Thanks for your correction.

You are not quoting Axler faithfully. He writes:$$f:[0,1]\to[0,\infty\color{red}].$$
Assume for instance that for some $x_0\in[0,1]$,
$$\forall n\in\Bbb N\quad0<x_0-r_{2n}\le2^{-4n}$$
(which is compatible with the other assumtions on the sequence $(r_k)$).
Then,
$$f(x_0)\ge\sum_{n\in\Bbb N}\frac{f_{2n}(x_0)}{2^{2n}}\ge\sum_{n\in\Bbb N}1=\infty.$$
